# How to do linear interpolation on with approx function in R

Tags: r, linear-interpolation

I have two NA's in my Data and I simply have to do a linear interpolation to find their value but I don't understand why it does not work.
Here is the data.
[It is quite big](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l3lgm.png).

Here is what i've tried:

```
id1 <- as.numeric(ID1)
anyNA(id1)
#There is 2 
sum(anyNA(id1))
is.na(id1)
na46 <- approx(x=c(95.4968:101.491), y=c(103.856 : 44.7562), method = "linear")
```

Comment: Welcome to SO :) adding a image of your data doesn't help too much, as we can't use it to run code and try to solve your problem. Read [How to make a great R reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/) and add your data to the question using the `dput()` function.

Comment: To fill the `NA` values in `ID1` you need to pass it to `approx`, and your code is not doing it currently. Maybe you want something like `approx(x = as.numeric(Year), y = as.numeric(ID1))`

Comment: Looking at the screen shot, you what to perform 2 interpolations, Once between `c(95.4968, 101.491)` and the other `c(103.856, 44.7562)` - this one rolls into the next region so you want to extrapolate from the previous 2.  For the first one use `approx(x=c(95.4968, 101.491), xout=1.5, method = "linear")$y`

Answer (score 0):

Use `na.approx`.  There are some arguments that can be used to specify how to deal with NA's on the ends.  It assumes that the data is equally spaced unless you use the x= argument to specify some other x values. See `?na.approx` for more details.

```
library(zoo)

y <- c(1, 2, NA, 4, 5, NA, 7)
na.approx(y)
## [1] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7

y2 <- c(NA, 1, NA, 2, NA)
na.approx(y2)
## [1] 1.0 1.5 2.0

na.approx(y2, na.rm = FALSE)
[1] NA 1.0 1.5 2.0 NA   

na.approx(y2, rule = 2)
## [1] 1.0 1.0 1.5 2.0 2.0

# BOD comes with R.  Create version where demand[5] is NA.
BOD2 <- transform(BOD, demand = replace(demand, 5, NA))
transform(BOD2, demand = na.approx(demand)) # without x=
##   Time demand
## 1    1    8.3
## 2    2   10.3
## 3    3   19.0
## 4    4   16.0
## 5    5   17.9
## 6    7   19.8
transform(BOD2, demand = na.approx(demand, x = Time)) # with x=
##   Time   demand
## 1    1  8.30000
## 2    2 10.30000
## 3    3 19.00000
## 4    4 16.00000
## 5    5 17.26667
## 6    7 19.80000
```